# Can you use Azure Policy to fail the validate stage of new VM creation?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am new to Azure, and looking into Azure policies which seem really cool, and I can get a policy working which will stop a virtual machine getting created if it has a SKU that I do not allow, which is great. My issue is that some other resources are created before the VM fails, i.e. the vnet etc.

Is it possible to create a policy that fails at the validation stage in the portal and therefore won't even let you click on the create button?

I understand that this won't work for ARM templates, but I can use my current policy for that.

I was hoping that during creation there would be a way of either limiting the dropdowns that the user sees or erroring if they pick the wrong dropdown item for a particular resource group

Comment: Kindly share the code, what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you use Azure Policy to fail the validate stage of new VM creation?

The policy will allow `VM` creation only if the `VM SKUs` match the specified ones. If the `SKUs` are not specified, it won't allow the next process in `VM` creation

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sku.name",
            "in": "[parameters('disallowedSKUs')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "Deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "disallowedSKUs": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Disallowed SKUs",
        "description": "List of SKUs that are not allowed for virtual machines."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The policy allows only specified `SKUs;` then, it proceeds to the next process.

[image]

**Disallowed Sku's in Policy:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Venkat V! My problem was the field I was querying, I was trying to check a field in 'Microsoft.Compute/disks/sku.tier' whereas I have now changed your example above to use 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.storageAccountType' as I wanted it to reject if the user selected Premium SSD as the OS disk type, and now it works a treat! Fails validation before anything is created. I assume this is because I am using properties from the virtualMachines type, and so that is why validation will fail rather than mine failing when it got to the disk creation.